# Using the VBA Filter Function to separate SQL results onto separate sheets

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to see if I can consolidate my current 3 separate queries into one, and use the **Filter** function in VBA to separate out the data on each sheet
so that I have tel (COMM001) on one sheet, mobiles (COMM004) on another and so on.
However the data just ends up with everything (COMM001, COMM004, COMM007) all showing on every sheet.

Can anyone advise on whether this is possible and if so  what it is I need to change in the below code?

```
Const sqlconnection = "Provider=visoledb;"

Dim conn As New Connection
conn.ConnectionString = sqlconnection
conn.Open
Dim rs As Recordset

Dim a1 As String
a1 = "SELECT id, sysdate, number, category FROM telephone s WHERE s.master_ty = 1 AND s.category IN ('COM001', 'COM004','COM007') "

Set rs = conn.Execute(a1)

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "TEL"
rs.Filter = "category='COMM001'"
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
.Refresh
End With

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "MOB"
rs.Filter = "category='COMM004'"
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
.Refresh
End With

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "EMAIL"
rs.Filter = "category='COMM007'"
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
.Refresh
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the recordset after filtering

Try this:

```
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "TEL"
rs.Filter = "category='COMM001'"
Set rsFiltered = rs.OpenRecordset
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rsFiltered ,Destination:=Range("A1"))
.Refresh
End With
```

Comment: It is highlighting ".OpenRecordset" and showing a "Compile error: Method or data member not found"

Comment: try: rs.Requery

Comment: That shows Compile error: Expected Function or variable